# Why javamail not sending E-mails in my PC?

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I use javamail v1.4.5.. This is my code

```
public boolean sendEmail(String reciver) {
    String usermail = "myemail@gmail.com";
    String password = "mypassword";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(usermail, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(usermail));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(reciver));// whome u have to send mails that person id
        message.setSubject("Subject");
        message.setText("Body");

        Transport.send(message);
        return true;

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Earlier (Before one year) this code worked for me in my pc smoothly. But now it prints these errors.

```
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1918)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:652)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.perisic.peripherals.Display.sendEmail(Display.java:96)
    at com.perisic.peripherals.Display.printpdf(Display.java:61)
    at com.perisic.beds.recycling.DepositItemReceiver.printpdf(DepositItemReceiver.java:57)
    at com.perisic.beds.recycling.CustomerPanel.printpdf(CustomerPanel.java:32)
    at com.perisic.peripherals.RecyclingGUI.actionPerformed(RecyclingGUI.java:37)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:548)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:485)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1913)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 54 more
```

now I run the same code in my friend's Pc but its worked in his Pc but not in my Pc.I Disabled my avast but still it returns same error. please tell me whats wrong with my pc.

I'm running windows8.1 64bit..

Comment: The exception is different, but are you sure that you turned on the less security app on gmail page? If no, log in the gmail account that you're using on a browser and check if it's on with this link https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps?pageId=none.

Comment: Another possible cause is a firewall on your machine, try to use telnet to check your connection to the smtp.gmail.com with this command on your cmd prompt: telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 if you don't have telnet, enable using this approach: https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-enable-the-telnet-client-in-windows-8-1/ or disabling the firewall for a test. For the last, if you are running in a eclipse instance, try to use another JRE or JDK to check if there's nothing wrong with your local installation.

Comment: This looks like a problem with TLS support in the JDK.  Did you upgrade the JDK recently?  Newer verrsions of the JDK disable support for older less secure versions of TLS, and if your server is older that might be a problem, although it should not be a problem with Gmail.  Maybe you need a newer JDK? And make sure Avast is really disabled.